# highlight item in spark list

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air, flex4

I have two spark lists and want to drag items from one list to the other. When im dragging an item and over the other list item, i want the target item to change the background coloer.

Basically instead of showing the black line indicating that I will drop between elements, I want to see the target item highlight.

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Something that would look similar to this drag and drop:
[image: drag item to list]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/SkrosMaBnaI/AAAAAAAAAWU/LQ4pF4TSR9M/dragndrop1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would ask you to point out a UI precedent where this is standard / expected behavior.

When you drag an itemA onto itemB; and itemB is highlighted somehow, it usually means you're dragging into ItemB.  But, in this case you are not dragging item from List1 into the item from List2.  [I assume at least].

You'd have to override the list code drag and drop features to make this happen.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Im overriding the drag and drop changing the background color, but I get a strange behaviour after I complete the drag. For instance, after the drag is complete, when I hover over the items they don't become blue.

This kind of UI can be seen in gmail where we can drag an email to a tag.

Comment: Hi Artur, which question does the bounty apply to? Based on the comment above it sounds like you have a solution for changing the background color and you have a follow up issue that the dropped items don't change color when hovered over.  Am I reading this right? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: I would also +1 my request for a running sample to demo your problem.

Comment: Just saw the comments today. The comment I made was to see if someone would give me a hint, but I don't really like the way I'm doing it, I would prefer a working/simple solution.

Comment: When I asked for a running sample; I meant your current code that I ould take and run; not a screeshot.